# Double-sectioned expandable tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am currently facing a big issue in my coding, but I can't find any solution.

[Just as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIQqI.jpg), I would like to create an expandable tableview with:

- categories split into 2 sections
- subcategories

I mean, if you click on "2A", the "2A-1", "2A-2" etc. list is expanded. If you click on "2B", the "2B-1", "2B-2" list is, and so on.

How do you think I could manage it?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a solution of this nature in a few products.  The code to accomplish this is a bit extensive, so I will give you a high level overview.

Create each "row" as a section.  Obviously, override `viewForHeaderInSection` and so forth in order to make each section header actually look like a row.

Have your view controller hold an array of which sections are expanded (non expanded are collapsed)

In the  `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`  check to see if the section is expanded, if it is, then return the number of subitems, otherwise, return 0.

hence, the cellForRowAtIndexPath always returns just the subItems, and the viewForHeaderInSection always returns the parent.

When the user clicks on the header cell, toggle the section expanded flag, and `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` to get a nice animated transition

one note, since prior to IOS6, section headers were ALWAYS recreated and NEVER cached, the performance was not great.  With IOS6, this issue is solved as it recycles header cells too.

Comment: You could do the same thing without headers and just return 1 in numberOfRowsInSection, which is your first row.  Then you don't have to "make each section header actually look like a row" and don't need to worry about the caching issue pre iOS6.  +1 though.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But I'm afraid I don't get it, maybe because I'm beginning : after creating the rows, how can I make possible to expand different subsections according to the clicking area (depending on left or right side) ?

Answer (score 0):

For expandable cells you can use [VPPDropDown](https://github.com/vicpenap/VPPDropDown) class, i used it myself, it's good :)